# Why does Plan 9 use "snarf" instead of "copy"?

Tags: history, terminology, plan9, command-names

When you watch presentations about Plan 9 and its `acme` editor you might notice that the name for *copy* is *snarf* (I wasn't able to find any meaningful explanation unfortunately).

Why is it so?

Is there a reason for that? Was it done to create a unique name for this functionality as *copy* might not be the best name?

---

#### References:

- [Wikipedia (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snarf):

  > Snarf, a term used for the "copy" operation in the Blit and Plan 9 windowing systems.
- [cat-v.org (link)](http://doc.cat-v.org/plan_9/misc/rit-intro):

  > There's another menu available with a mid-click; Cut and Paste are pretty
  >   self-explanatory, and Snarf is just the Plan 9 word for Copy.
- [9fans mailing list (link)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.plan9/9-RsMHsnsOM):

  > > Using either/both acme under Plan 9 and/or Mac OS X via plan9port, is 
  > >     there a "file" that can be opened in acme that displays the current 
  > >     contents of the acme snarf buffer?
  >
  > ```
  > /dev/snarf
  > ```

  So it looks like that there is something like a *snarf buffer* and a file (obviously there must be a file for that buffer) called `/dev/snarf`.
- [9term manual page (link)](https://swtch.com/plan9port/man/man1/9term.html):

  > Characters typed on the keyboard replace the selected text; if this text is not empty, it is placed in a snarf buffer common to all windows but distinct from that of sam(1).
  >
  > (...)
  >
  > Editing operations are selected from a menu on button 2. The cut operation deletes the selected text from the screen and puts it in the snarf buffer; snarf copies the selected text to the buffer without deleting it; paste replaces the selected text with the contents of the buffer; and send copies the snarf buffer to just after the output point, adding a final newline if missing. Paste will sometimes and send will always place text after the output point; the text so placed will behave exactly as described above. Therefore when pasting text containing newlines after the output point, it may be prudent to turn on hold mode first.
- [*Exploring Acme* tutorial (link)](http://blog.suspended-chord.info/2013/11/26/exploring-acme/):

  > 'Snarf': called copy in most other editors
- [dictionary.com definitions of *snarf* (link)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/snarf):

  - > (informal) to eat or drink greedily
  - > (contemporary) to grab something in greed, esp. without permission
  - > (Unix) To fetch a file or set of files across a network. See also blast.
- [Inferno Part 2: Let's Make a Cluster! (link)](http://debu.gs/entries/inferno-part-2-let-s-make-a-cluster):

  > The clipboard is called by the unfortunate name “snarf buffer” in Inferno and Plan 9.

Comment: I asked about the reason of putting the question on hold on meta: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4163/closing-votes-on-a-historic-question-about-plan-9

Comment: I would guess it's a "verbalization", same as when people say "google it" , so "snarf" was just a way to say "put text into snarf buffer".

Comment: @Serg But why "snarf buffer", not "copy buffer"?

Comment: @Serg You mean verbification, not verbalization -- to verbalize is to say aloud.

Comment: If I were to guess it may be similar to `clojure`'s design.  In clojure you use `slurp` and `spit` for file IO, `snarf` is not far off.  (But clojure is much younger than Plan9)

Comment: @Serg it can't really be a verbification, it was already a verb before Plan 9; see [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snarf) for the various definitions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I stumbled upon a quite reasonable explanation today. The [Jargon File (link)](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/snarf.html) explains *snarf* like this:

> **[snarf](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/snarf.html)**: /snarf/, vt.
>
> 2. [in the Unix community] To fetch a file or set of files across a network. See also [blast](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/blast.html). This term was mainstream in the late 1960s, meaning ‘*to eat piggishly*’. It may still have this connotation in context. “*He's in the snarfing phase of hacking — FTPing megs of stuff a day.*”

It seems like the designers of Plan 9 perceived *copy* not as an atomic action. *Copying* is in fact:

- obtaining the content you want to copy (*snarfing*)
- inserting the content where you want it to be (*pasting*)

(*Cutting* on the other hand is *snarfing* and *deleting* the original content at the same time.)

---

#### Rob Pike's answer

I've asked this question on the 9fans mailing list. You can see [the thread here (link)<sup>1</sup>](http://mail.9fans.net/private/9fans/2016-September/035426.html).

Here's [the answer<sup>1</sup>](http://mail.9fans.net/private/9fans/2016-September/035429.html) I've received from Rob Pike:

> The operation is not to copy but to snarf. It's called snarf because
>   snarf is what it does. There is no design document.

---

<sup>1:
As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) pointed out in a comment, you can use http://marc.info/?t=147367568900005&r=1&w=2 to avoid having to create an account to see the list archives.</sup>

Comment: Now the phrase "bluesnarfing" makes sense